# Tilde when clicking <Del> key

Tags: keyboard, xfce4-terminal

I am using XFCE Terminal emulator 0.4.8.

My ~/.inputrc file:

```
# Insert Key
"\e[2~": paste-from-clipboard
"\C-v": paste-from-clipboard
"\e[A":history-search-backward
"\e[B":history-search-forward
"\M-[3~": delete-char
```

When I click `<Del>` a tilde is printed instead of deleting the next character. When I remove .inputrc file, it starts working correctly. Googling showed, that this line:

```
"\M-[3~": delete-char
```

has helped people to cure this. But not me. I inserted this line into .inputrc, even deleted all the other lines. Doesn't work.

How to fix?

Comment: `"\e[3~": delete-char` should work better

Comment: @sendmoreinfo This is great, but when I delete a line completely with Ctrl-D, using your code, it just closes the console.

Comment: That's C-d default action (to send EOF).  You could change that with `stty eof`

Comment: @sendmoreinfo I used "export IGNOREEOF=42" to make 42 consecutive Ctrl-D clicks exist the shell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The line

```
"\M-[3~": delete-char
```

is incorrect because it tells bash to look for the *meta* character for <kbd>`[`</kbd>, which (according to bash) could be the escape character followed by `[`, or it could be the character formed by OR'ing `[` with 0x80, i.e., 0xdb which is <kbd>`Û`</kbd>

The actual key would use just the escape character, so you should use this setting:

```
"\e[3~": delete-char
```

Comment: In my case using **mintty** , the **"\M-[3~": delete-char** was the correct bind to get rid of the TILDE :-/

Answer (score 3):

Although the question has been answered already, I'd like to mention (for others) that this depends on your shell because I had the very same problem but with zsh. The problem is that zsh does not use readline and hence doesn't read the inputrc. Instead they implemented the zsh line editor (zle).

The solution I found was to explicitely set the key binding (so for the zle instead of readline) in your zshrc as it is [described in the arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Zsh#Key_bindings)

```
# create a zkbd compatible hash;
typeset -g -A key
key[Delete]="${terminfo[kdch1]}"

# setup key accordingly
[[ -n "${key[Delete]}"    ]] && bindkey -- "${key[Delete]}"     delete-char
```